# How to change background color in a moon_reader presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

I am struggling to change the background color of my presentation that I am constructing with xaringan::moon_reader, Rmarkdown and Rstudio.

Here is my code:

````
---
title: "Changing CSS"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader: default
---

```{css, echo = FALSE}
body {
  color: red;
  background-color: blue;
}
```


# Hello 

Some content

---

# Hello 2

Another Content
````

I see that the "color: red" is acknowledged but not the background color. Do I have a mistake in my code ? Or did I misunderstand something?

Thanks in advance for your answers,

Charlotte

Answer (score 1):

Instead of body, apply these css rule for the class `.remark-slide-content`.

````
---
title: "Changing CSS"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader: default
---

```{css, echo = FALSE}
.remark-slide-content {
  color: red;
  background-color: blue;
}
```


# Hello 

Some content

---
background-color: blue

# Hello 2

Another Content
````